# Sequential numbers in a list haskell

Tags: list, loops, haskell

I am new to haskell and I was attempting a few coding problems that I previously completed for java, however the following problem has me stumped.

Basically the idea is to write a function that takes in a list of integers ([Int]) establishes whether a list of integers has consecutive 1's within it. For example the output of the following would be:
Input: func [0,0,1,1,0]
Output: True

A sample solution for this problem in haskell would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: In regards to the logic:  
Check for empty list or singleton and return false, if first element is 0 check the rest of the list for sequences, if the first element is 1 check the second element for 1 and return true else check the list from the third element.

`def sequeceones list
 if list == [] then false;
 else if (tail list) == [] then false;
 else if (head list) == 0 then (sequeceones (tail list))
 else if (head list) == 1 then if (head (tail list)) == 1 then true else (sequeceones (tail (tail list)))
`
My issue is im not sure how to write that in haskell

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to use pattern matching to look for consecutive ones at the head of the list, and advance down the list until you find them, or you run out of elements to look at.

```
consecutiveOnes [] = False
consecutiveOnes (1:1:_) = True
consecutiveOnes (_:xs) = consecutiveOnes xs
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution:

```
consecutiveOnes :: [Int] -> Bool
consecutiveOnes xs = auxOnes False xs

auxOnes :: Bool -> [Int] -> Bool
auxOnes b [] = False
auxOnes b (x:xs) = case (x==1 && b) of {
    True -> True;
    False -> auxOnes (x==1) xs;
};
```

Another way would be using the [isInfixOf method](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf) and asking if [1,1] appears anywhere on your list:

```
consecutiveOnes :: [Int] -> Bool
consecutiveOnes xs = isInfixOf [1,1] xs
```

> The isInfixOf function takes two lists and returns True iff the first
> list is contained, wholly and intact, anywhere within the second.

But I'm sure there are many other ways of doing it.

Comment: Awesome, definitely a lot neater than my approach would have been, thanks a million.

Comment: I just added a new one thats way neater, but check the Data.List methods https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html since there are maaaaany ways you could get this done

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way:

```
consecutiveOnes [] = False
consecutiveOnes xs = any (== (1,1)) $ zip xs (tail xs)
```

If

```
 xs == [0,1,1,2,3,4]
```

Then

```
tail xs == [1,1,2,3,4]
```

Zipping them together you get a list of pairs, where each pair is an element of the list and the element after it.

```
zip xs (tail xs) == [(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```